# Injecting Dependencies using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Consider I have one interface.

```
interface Interface<A> {}
```

Now I have 2 classes which implement this interface:

```
class ClassOne<A>: I<A> {}
class ClassTwo<A>: I<A> {}
```

Now I want to use these 2 classes in a third class.

```
class child
{
    child(Interface<A> objCA,Interface<A> objCB)
    {}
}
```

I am not able to inject the dependency for child class using Castle Windsor. Even if I inject it, it is passing only one object to all of them. So how can I resolve this scenario using Castle Windsor?

Comment: You can't register 2 implementations of an interface and expect Windsor to know which service to use. You can customize the resolution pipeline in order to give Windsor hints though. You could also use the collection resolver which will give you all types of a particular service...

Comment: Details here https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using Castle Windsor collection/array/list resolvers.

Take a look: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md

This way you will be able to get the same behavior with slightly different syntax.

Configure the container like this:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

Register CA and CB like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<CA>());
container.Register(Component.For<IA>().ImplementedBy<CB>());
```

and change your class to:

```
class child
{
    child(IEnumerable<IA> objs)
    {}
}
```